# AWS Batch command with no spaces?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-batch

I have a command I am trying to run, `minimus2 <prefix> -D OVERLAP=100 -D MINID=95 -D THREADS=1` and there can be no spaces for the `-D` commands, e.g. `minimus2 <prefix> -D OVERLAP 100 -D MINID 95 -D THREADS 1`, will fail.

I've tried,

```
"Command":[
  "minimus2",
  "Ref::afgPrefixFile",
  "-D",
  "OVERLAP=",
  "Ref::overlap",
  "-D",
  "MINID=",
  "Ref::minid",
  "-D",
  "THREADS=",
  "Ref::threads"
]
```

which returns `minimus2 <prefix file> -D OVERLAP= 100 -D MINID= 95 -D THREADS= 1`, this will add a space after the `=` and causes the command to fail. And,

```
"Command":[
  "minimus2",
  "Ref::afgPrefixFile",
  "-D",
  "OVERLAP=Ref::overlap",
  "-D",
  "MINID=Ref::minid",
  "-D",
  "THREADS=Ref::threads"
]
```

Which doesn't work.  How can I build an AWS Batch command where some parameters don't generate spaces?

Comment: Any reason not to just set your parameters to the whole string? For example `"parameters" : {"overlap" : "OVERLAP=THE_VALUE", ....}` Not ideal I know

Comment: @rainkinz - you know I hadn't thought of that!! Not ideal but would work.

Comment: Definitely not ideal, but this is basically how we handle it :-/

Comment: someone needs to fork amos and start new development on it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not ideal I know, but you could set your parameters to the whole string? For example:

```
"parameters" : {"overlap" : "OVERLAP=THE_VALUE", ....}
```